# .htaccess : Rewrite Rule from URL to POST / SESSION parameter

Tags: .htaccess

If I wish to forward from :

```
http://www.domain.com/system/link1
http://www.domain.com/system/link2
http://www.domain.com/system/link3
```

to :

```
http://www.domain.com/system/  // forward to the index.php
```

while the **index.php** can receive parameter `link1` , `link2` and `link3` in **$_POST** or in **$_SESSION**. How should I write the `.htaccess` rule?

My current rule is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /system/?systemkey=$1 ^system/([^/]*)$  [L]
```

but I am sure it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it receive in `$_SESSION` or `$_POST`, only `$_GET`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^system/([^/]*)/?$ system/index.php?systemkey=$1  [L]
```

Comment: seems reversed `from` & `to` .

Comment: Try it and you'll know for sure :)

Comment: `http://www.domain.com/system/link1` now forwards to `http://www.domain.com/system/?systemkey=index.php` using your answer. Where does `link1` gone?

Comment: That's impossible. It should go here: `system/index.php?systemkey=link1` (I tested it). Can you try again? Make sure there are no rules above this or anything.